# footer with position:fixed overlaps page content

Tags: html, css

I don't have a "sticky footer", I want the footer to always take a certain height at the bottom of the page and the content adjust to the footer (not vice versa). By content adjusting to the footer I mean a scrollbar appearing and the content start scrolling. It works until a certain browser window size and at the smaller sizes the footer starts to cover the content - instead of the scrollbar of textholder div getting longer. Why is that and is there a way to fix it?

http://clients.idea-bureau.com/test/fixed_footer.html

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>fixed footer</title>

<style>
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
#container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    min-height:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;


}

#content{
    float:left;
    width: 55%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color:orange;


}

#textholder{
    width:80%;
    height:90%;
    font-size:1.5em;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    background-color:#996633;
    overflow:auto;

}
#footer{

    position: fixed;
    height: 155px;
    width:100%;;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #069;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">

<div id ="textholder">
A motorist in a Mercedes was driving through the countryside on a beautiful Saturday afternoon, having a lovely time, when he came to an area of the road that was covered with a rather large puddle of water from a previous rain storm. Worried that he was going to damage the car and its engine in the deep water, he asked a local farmer (who just happened to be standing near the large pool of water) how deep the water was. "Arr", said the local farmer "That water only be a few inches deep!" Relieved, the motorist edged his car into the water, expecting to come out the other side in no time. Instead, as he drove in, the water came right up the side of the car, and the engine sputtered to a halt. Sitting there with the water along with and a floating weed lapping at the window, the motorist yelled at the local angrily: "I thought you said this water was only a few inches deep!!!" "Well", replied the local farmer "It only come up to the waist of them there ducks!"
<p>
A motorist in a Mercedes was driving through the countryside on a beautiful Saturday afternoon, having a lovely time, when he came to an area of the road that was covered with a rather large puddle of water from a previous rain storm. Worried that he was going to damage the car and its engine in the deep water, he asked a local farmer (who just happened to be standing near the large pool of water) how deep the water was. "Arr", said the local farmer "That water only be a few inches deep!" Relieved, the motorist edged his car into the water, expecting to come out the other side in no time. Instead, as he drove in, the water came right up the side of the car, and the engine sputtered to a halt. Sitting there with the water along with and a floating weed lapping at the window, the motorist yelled at the local angrily: "I thought you said this water was only a few inches deep!!!" "Well", replied the local farmer "It only come up to the waist of them there ducks!"
</div>
</div>
<div id = "footer"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content has `Height:70%` so your footer can have maximum of 30% of total Height otherwise it will overlap the content. As currently you have `155px` which is more than 30% of the total height. So change it to 30% and then try.

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
height: 30%;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
background-color: #069;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! I am just starting to work with percentages again and looks like one should not mix pixels with percentages!